# Растянуть заголовок таблицы в соответствии с контентом

Tags: html, css

Предисловие: ширина столбца таблицы растягивается в зависимости от содержимого. Кол-во ячеек в заголовке всегда соответствует кол-ву столбцов в теле таблицы. Ширина для thead, tbody - 100%.

Возникла проблема: ширина ячейки заголовка - равна ширине контента. Таким образом, получается что ячейка заголовка не совпадает с ячейкой столбца в теле таблицы, т.е. заголовок съезжает. Как сделать, чтобы ширина ячейки заголовка была равна ширине столбца в теле таблицы? Явно указывать ширину для ячейки заголовка - не подходит, нужно именно сделать зависимость от ширины содержимого в теле таблицы.

Структура HTML такая:

```
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
            ...
      </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
            ...
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Вы таблицу-то контентом сперва заполните, а то наглядно не ясно в чём проблема. Код скопировал, своими значениями заполнил, ничего не съезжает, всё нормально..

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию все прекрасно совпадает, это штатное поведение таблиц. Более того, ширина заголовка и тела совпадает даже если стилями задать жесткие различия (я добавил в пример max-width для заголовка и min-width для тела). Если у вас не так - ищите проблему в стилях, может у вас `display` для частей таблицы переопределен.

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 15px 40px;
}

thead {
  max-width: 200px;
}

tbody {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```